# How to use read instead of execute in a function?

Tags: vimscript, grep

I'm trying to search for the selected line of a file using the following:

```
function! GrepSelection()
    normal! gvy
    let result = escape(@", '\\/.*$^~[]#')
    let result = substitute(result, "\n$", "", "")
    let result = substitute(result, "\n", '\\n', "g")
    new | setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile
    execute 'grep "'.result.'" file'
endfunction
xnoremap <silent> <unique> * :<C-U>call GrepSelection()<CR>
```

but it seems it fail when i replace the `execute` part with `read !` (it also fail with `read!`). Yet it does work when i do this manually on the commandline.

The way it fail is:

```
/bin/bash: grep ".result." file: No such file or directory
```

where it obviously does find the file, but the problem here is the fact that ".result." is taken literally, instead of being replaced with the selected string (like when `execute` is used instead).

Anything wrong with what I'm doing here?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. How does it fail? Does it give an error, or does it just not do the correct thing?

Comment: just added a brief explanation on how it fail (and nearly at the same time you commented) :)

Comment: Yeah, i only tried with `read !`. Just tried with `read! {cmd}` but it doesn't seem to work and return the same error.

Comment: It looks like you're reinventing `:vimgrep`, the Vim command `:grep`, the `'grepprg'` option, the quickfix list... Have you looked into what those do and whether they maybe do exactly what you want?

Comment: yeah, already checked them but i wanted something a bit different. (which your solution helped to make) @filbranden

Comment: Also consider you can do a lot of that in Vim itself. For example, the `:v` command (see `:help :vglobal`) can be used to delete lines not matching a pattern. So `new | 0read file | v/pattern/d` will get you a buffer with only the lines in `file` that match `pattern`... No need to run an external `grep` and interact with the shell!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need the `execute`, in order to interpolate the contents of the `result` Vimscript variable into the shell command:

```
execute 'read !grep "'.result.'" file'
```

Note that now this is a *shell* command and no longer just a Vim command, so consider using [`shellescape()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#shellescape%28%29) to properly escape the string for use in a shell command. (But note that you may need to adapt the rest of the script for that to work correctly.)